# Is there a way to find the kinetics data for the strong acid weak base reaction?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, kinetics

I am layman of chemistry. Latterly, I am asked to do an mathematical optimization task for a bio-chemical process, which contains a conditioning step to neutralize the sulfuric acid using ammonia hydroxide. I am trying to use the mathematical model of the reaction (kinetic model) to optimize the reaction time/energy/efficiency (target not determined yet). However, I could not find the kinetics data. Is there a way I could find the kinetic model of the reaction?

Another question is that: Should I treated this reaction as an element reaction and use third-order reaction rate formula?

I am confused by a former post ([Finding rate of acid - base reaction](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16758/finding-rate-of-acid-base-reaction)). In that post, the accepted answer says "Typical acid - base reactions that occur in solution are diffusion controlled reactions. Such reactions do not follow second order kinetics because at virtually every encounter of the acid and base, rapid proton transfer occurs and the reaction is complete. " Should I use the diffusion control model instead of the reaction rate model?

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: "Should I use the diffusion control model instead of the reaction rate model?" Acid base reactions are among the fastest reactions in chemistry. As soon as the solutions are mixed, the reaction can be considered complete, so the rate determining step is the diffusion/mixing of the two solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will look into the diffusion model then.