# How to achieve highest CO2 pressure from acetic acid + sodium bicarbonate reaction?

Tags: acid-base, home-experiment, applied-chemistry, carbon-dioxide

I'm planning to make a high-end vinegar + baking soda rocket and started doing some researches for the best ratio of the reagents's concentrations to achieve maximum pressure. Furthermore, I know that the temperature of the vinegar affects the reaction, so, what's the best temperature, the hotter the better?

If you know any other ways to make the reaction faster, I'd like to know. For context, I have a 2 liter bottle and would like to achieve 250+ psi. Is it possible to achieve this pressure with the reaction happening inside this bottle, or a separate vessel would be needed?

Comment: Reaction can hardly be "better" - results can be, and in your case it's speed, or more precisely higher rate. To achieve that, not only temperature and concentrations are relevant, but primarily the speed of mixing. Also don't add "thanks", you can do it later in comment.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16758/comparing-rate-of-reaction-of-acetic-acid-and-sodium-bicarbonate-at-different-te

Comment: 250 PSI seems impossible, see [here](http://www.water-rockets.com/article.pl?106,0).